# Why is my xsd:pattern failing to match my XML?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

My XSD is failing to validate my XML.

I have the following in my XSD:

```
    <xsd:element name="Phone">
        <xsd:simpleType>
            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                <xsd:pattern value="^\d{0,11}$"/>
            </xsd:restriction>
        </xsd:simpleType>
    </xsd:element>
```

And in my XML file, I have the following element:

```
<Phone>0653556048</Phone>
```

When I validate my XML file against my XSD file, I catch this errors:

> Value '0653556048' is not facet-valid with respect to pattern
> '^\d{0,11} $' for type '#AnonType_PhoneUserForm'.

But when I test the validation regex on a regex website, my attribute is valid:

[image]

Both my XML and XSD files are UTF-8.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Regex in `xsd:pattern` values are implicitly anchored at the start (`^`) and end (`$`) of the string, so change

```
            <xsd:pattern value="^\d{0,11}$"/>
```

to

```
            <xsd:pattern value="\d{0,11}"/>
```

and your XSD will validate your XML successfully.